# Calculate number of cycles available between dates and arrange row value as column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, pivot

I have the vehicle information data in SQL as following order,

| S.No | Vehicle_ID | status | date_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Start | 2018-05-23 |
| 2 | 1 | Start | 2021-06-15 |
| 3 | 1 | Failed | 2020-08-10 |
| 4 | 2 | Start | 2019-06-23 |
| 5 | 3 | Start | 2010-04-20 |
| 6 | 3 | Failed | 2010-05-10 |
| 7 | 4 | Start | 2011-01-20 |
| 8 | 4 | Failed | 2015-01-14 |
| 9 | 4 | Start | 2016-02-25 |
| 10 | 4 | Failed | 2019-04-10 |

**Vehicle ID : 1**

1st **start** date = 2018-05-23

1st **failed** =2020-08-10

2nd **start** date = 2021-06-15

Here, there is no failed date for 2nd **start** date so we take **today's** date as failed date.

**Vehicle ID : 2**

1st **start** date = 2020-08-10

Here, there is no failed date for 1st **start** date so we take **today's** date as failed date.

Based on above condition, Required result as per below,

| Vehicle_ID | Start | Failed/Running | Cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-05-23 | 2020-08-10 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-06-15 | Today's date | 2 |
| 2 | 2019-06-23 | Today's date | 1 |
| 3 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-05-10 | 1 |
| 4 | 2011-01-20 | 2015-01-14 | 1 |
| 4 | 2016-02-25 | 2019-04-10 | 2 |

I tried PIVOT function for switching row to column but I am straggle to assign the Cycle and date order.

Tried code shown below,

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    S_No,
    Vehicle_ID,
    date_on,
    status
    
  FROM vehicle_table where Vehicle_ID is not null  Group by Vehicle_ID,status,S_No,date_on 
) Vehicle_Detail
PIVOT (
  MAX(date_on) 
  FOR status
  IN (
    [Start],
    [Failed]
    
  )
) AS PivotTable where [status] is not null order by [Vehicle_ID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `outer apply top 1` construct here

```sql
create table vehicle_detail (S_No int,  Vehicle_ID int, status varchar(6),  date_on date);

insert vehicle_detail values
(1,   1, 'Start',  '2018-05-23'),
(2,   1, 'Start',  '2021-06-15'),
(3,   1, 'Failed', '2020-08-10'),
(4,   2, 'Start',  '2019-06-23'),
(5,   3, 'Start',  '2010-04-20'),
(6,   3, 'Failed', '2010-05-10'),
(7,   4, 'Start',  '2011-01-20'),
(8,   4, 'Failed', '2015-01-14'),
(9,   4, 'Start',  '2016-02-25'),
(10,  4, 'Failed', '2019-04-10');


select      starts.vehicle_id,
            start             =  starts.date_on,
            [failed/running]  =  isnull(fails.date_on, cast(getdate() as date)),
            cycle             =  row_number() over 
                                 (
                                    partition by starts.vehicle_id 
                                    order by starts.date_on asc
                                 )
from        vehicle_detail  starts
outer apply (
               select    top 1 date_on
               from      vehicle_detail v
               where     v.vehicle_id = starts.vehicle_id
               and       v.status = 'Failed'
               and       v.date_on >= starts.date_on
               order by  date_on asc
            ) fails
where       starts.status = 'Start'
order by    starts.vehicle_id,
            starts.date_on;
```

Comment: I am getting exact result using above your statement. thanks for giving suggested code

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be a simple left join and a subquery:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  SNo INT
 ,Vehicle_ID int
 ,stat VARCHAR(10)
 ,date_on DATE
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1     ,1     ,'Start', '2018-05-23')
,(2     ,1     ,'Start', '2021-06-15')
,(3     ,1     ,'Failed', '2020-08-10')
,(4     ,2     ,'Start', '2019-06-23')
,(5     ,3     ,'Start', '2010-04-20')
,(6     ,3     ,'Failed', '2010-05-10')
,(7     ,4     ,'Start', '2011-01-20')
,(8     ,4     ,'Failed', '2015-01-14')
,(9     ,4     ,'Start', '2016-02-25')
,(10     ,4     ,'Failed', '2019-04-10');

WITH cte AS(
SELECT t.Vehicle_ID, t.stat, t.date_on AS StartDate, ISNULL(LEAD(DATEADD(d, -1, t.date_on)) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Vehicle_ID ORDER BY t.date_on), t.date_on) AS StartDateNext
  FROM @t t
  WHERE t.stat = 'Start'
)
SELECT t.Vehicle_ID
      ,t.StartDate
      ,ISNULL(te.date_on, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS FailedRunningDate
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Vehicle_ID ORDER BY t.StartDate) AS Cycle
  FROM cte t
    LEFT JOIN @t te ON te.Vehicle_ID = t.Vehicle_ID
                  AND te.stat = 'Failed'
                  AND te.date_on >= t.StartDate
                  AND te.date_on <= t.StartDateNext
```

Comment: I am getting exact result using above your statement. thanks for suggested code

Answer (score 0):

Provided there's no any fail without a start, you can match start / fail by row_number()

```
with ordered as(
   SELECT 
    S_No,
    Vehicle_ID,
    date_on,
    status,
    row_number() over(partition by Vehicle_ID, status order by date_on) rn 
   FROM vehicle_table 
   WHERE Vehicle_ID is not null
)
select s.Vehicle_ID, s.date_on start, s.rn cycle, coalesce(f.date_on, getdate()) [Failed/Running]
from ordered s
left join ordered f on s.Vehicle_ID = f.Vehicle_ID and s.rn = f.rn
   and f.status ='Failed'
   -- sanity check 
   and (s.date_on <= f.date_on or f.date_on is null)
where s.status ='Start'
order by s.Vehicle_ID, s.date_on, s.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to sort your data the way you want

```
WITH tSortRaw
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY vehicle_id, STATUS 
            ORDER BY date_on DESC
            ) [R],
        *
    FROM Vehicle_Detail
    ),
tMerge
AS (
    SELECT tStart.vehicle_id,
        tStart.date_on [Start],
        IIF(tFailed.date_on IS NULL, GETDATE(), tFailed.date_on) [Failed]
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM tSortRaw
        WHERE STATUS = 'Start'
        ) [tStart]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM tSortRaw
        WHERE STATUS = 'Failed'
        ) [tFailed]
        ON tStart.vehicle_id = tFailed.vehicle_id
            AND tStart.R = tFailed.R
    )
SELECT vehicle_id,
    Start,
    Failed [Failed/Running],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID
        ORDER BY Start
        ) [Cycle]
FROM tMerge
```